# General Question about (Hyper)parameter optimization via Python

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, scipy, minimize

I have a dataset with numerical values. Those values are used alongside constants to calculate different factors. Based on these factors decisions are made which ultimately lead to a single numerical value.

My goal is to find the maximum (or minimum when multiplied by -1) of this numerical value by changing those constants.

I have been looking at the library SciPy Hyperparamater optimization (machine learning) and minimize(). But after reading through several tutorials I am a little bit lost on which one to use and how to implement it.

Is there someone who would be so kind and guide me onto the right track?

Comment: I think you are already on the right track, you just need to experiment more and learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as my research went I have to feed minimize() with a mathematical function which I do not have since my numerical value is dependend on a decision tree (which I couldn't figure out how to write down into a formula). So I guess machine learning is the way to go?